# Flying units against flying units in air and on land

Tags: warhammer-total-war, warhammer-ii-total-war

Up till now I have always either intercepted opposing flying units with my own(when mine are stronger) or lure them to land and use my flying units to attack their artillery or other range units(when mine are weaker). Instead I am thinking if there might be certain advantages if both flying unit fight on the ground instead of in air?

I tried to test this out but since there needs to be land units present for flying units to land on fight, I cannot reliably conclude if there are any advantages in doing so. I am asking this question in hope someone know of certain data or somehow manage to make two flying units combat on the ground to see the difference.

So my question is when flying units fight against flying units, is there a difference if they fight in the air or on the ground?

Comment: You can test this quite easily I think. As far as I know, flying units are forced to land, when there are no ground units left in their army. So grab a friend. You both use a flying Lord and only flying units. They should all be forced to land.

Comment: Erm... That forced to land is not that they must be grounded... It means that the flying side must engage within a certain period of time or loose that fight. If both sides only have flying they will still engage in air. I believe the defending side will win if neither side choose to engage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So my question is when flying units fight against flying units, is
>   there a difference if they fight in the air or on the ground?

Its only doable if you have one flyer attack a ground unit, then the other flyer either attacks the now grounded flyer, or attacks a nearby enemy unit, then moves to attack the other flyer. There was a particular animation when two dragons faced off that would have one do a pile-driver to the other, they'd end up on the ground and fight for about 1-2 attack cycles before taking off and re-engaging in the air, but that animation was disabled and was very unlikely to occur.

There is a performance difference, flyers get their charge bonus when attacking from the air, they have no "charge" on the ground. This means that units dependent on their charge bonus like Great Eagles, or Feral Manticores, are at a severe disadvantage as they cannot charge while grounded, they have an abysmal Melee Defense, and a pretty weak Melee Attack without the charge-bonus to buff it.

Comment: I am sure that when I order a landed flying unit to attack a unit a short distance aways it'd also perform a running attack. Does that not have charge bonus?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, no it didn't at that time, AFAIK there hasn't been patch that adjusted that.